# google pagespeed with nginx and apacher recommendable? Where to install?

Tags: apache, nginx, pagespeed, mod-pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I'm running a setup with an nginx frontend server and apache as backend server.

Where would you set up pagespeed? Is it still possible to install mod_pagespeed in apache in this setting? My webserver is not directly accessible!

Any experiences how much performance boost google pagespeed brings in such a setting? Is it recommendable at all?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your situation is:

```
+------+       +-------+       +--------+
| user | ----> | nginx | ----> | apache |
+------+       +-------+       +--------+
```

This is a very common setup, and people have had good results with two options:

1) Install mod_pagespeed on the apache backend, or
2) Install ngx_pagespeed on the nginx frontend.

Either is reasonable, just only install in one of the two places.  If you have multiple backends then installing on the frontend is better.  If you have enough traffic flowing through your frontend that additionally running pagespeed is too much for that server, then installing on the backends is better.  If you install on multiple backends, though, use memcached and have them share a cache, and make sure they all have identical pagespeed versions and configurations.

Comment: what if I have 2 nginx with 2 apache. so to speack user --> loadbalancer --> nginx --> loadbalancer --> application server?